# How to create an object with a property that is the sum of other properties in the same object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm having a lot of trouble with this and cannot seem to find the correct answer anywhere. I'm creating an object A with various properties, and one of those properties is the sum of two others, like below:

```
    var A = {
       a:0,
       b:0,
       c: this.a + this.b
    };
```

Where my issue comes in is that at run time when I reference A.c, I get NaN instead of 0, or whatever value it should be based on what I have assigned to a and b.

Please he;p. I'm completely confused.

Comment: I should note that I am using a method within the object to call those properties. For instance the method would be assign_values: function() {A.a = 6; A.b = 9;} - and then I'm expecting A.c to be 15.

Answer (score 2):

Because the context `this` is not a reference of object `A`, rather is a reference 
of the enclosing scope, i.e `window`.

So, `this.a + this.b` `-->` `undefined + undefined` `-->` `NaN`.

*Example to illustrate the enclosing scope (in this case the object `window`):*

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 5;

var A = {
  a: 0,
  b: 2,
  c: this.a + this.b
};

console.log(A.c);
```

An alternative is binding a function to that property `c` using a **[`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)**.

```js
var A = {
  a: 0,
  b: 2,
  get c() {
    return this.a + this.b
  }
};

console.log(A.c);
A.a = 33;
console.log(A.c);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Problem is I am using A.c in binding to my UI in a Nativescript app, so that A.c (or just {{ c }} in my case) needs to update the UI automatically if either A.a or A.b changes at any given point. My workaround for this was to redo the calculation and assign the result to A.c each time a calculation was done and something changed in either A.a or A.b. Would this be okay or is your way the better option?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap A's c value (A.c) into a function like this:

```
var A = {
   a:9,
   b:2,
   c:function() {
       return this.a + this.b
   }
};


console.log(A.c());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    evtChange: function (v) { /* event on any (a, b) changes */
        console.log("property changed >> " + v)
    },
    _a: 70,
    _b: 80,
    set a(v) {
        if (v !== this._a) { /* to prevent unwanted recalculation for complexe calcul statements */
            this._a = v;
            this.c = this._a + this._b;
            this.evtChange(this.c);
        }
    },
    get a() {
        return this._a;
    },
    set b(v) {
        if (v !== this._b) { /* to prevent unwanted recalculation for complexe calcul statements */
            this._b = v;
            this.c = this._a + this._b
            this.evtChange(this.c);
        }
    },
    get b() {
        return this._b;
    },
    /* using getter memo
    ** if we call obj.c first, getter methode will be replaced with a property.
    ** getter methode will be replaced too on any setters (a, b) call
    */ 
    get c() {
        delete this.c; // delete getter
        return this.c = this._a + this._b // replace getter imediately with c property
    }
};

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.c);
console.log(obj);
obj.a = 500;
obj.b = 2000;
console.log(obj.c);
```

console output:

```
/*obj*/
{evtChange: ƒ, _a: 70, _b: 80}
/*obj.c*/
150
/*obj*/
{evtChange: ƒ, _a: 70, _b: 80, c: 150}
/*obj.a = 500*/
property changed >> 580
/*obj.b = 2000;*/
property changed >> 2500
/*obj.c*/
2500
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: This was my workaround. I need A.c to update automatically based on changes to A.a and A.b, so when referring to A.c I automatically get the latest value, without needing to recalculate it.